# Is there anything wrong with the phrase "constant variable" ? (used in context with programming)

Tags: phrases, semantics

The phrase "constant variable" seems semantically incorrect to me. Constant means something that don't change and variable means something that do change. How should I think in order to get this ?

Comment: In Java, for example, `Integer foo`, `foo` is a *variable*; and in `final Integer foo = 42`, `foo` is now a *constant variable*. In other words, *variable* is used to express more than one idea in the context of computer programming.  Now, how do you feel about "*Given `x^2 - 6x + 2 = 0`, solve for the **variable** `x`*" in algebra, when *by definition* `x` *doesn't vary*?

Comment: If it changes (or can be changed), it's a variable. If it doesn't, it's a constant. pi and c are constants.

Comment: @DanBron `x` does vary, and can vary. It's only when `x` is a member of the set of answers does the equation conform, but `x` is not always that set of answers for all equations that hold `x`.

Comment: @DanBron, Then what about *"Given ax^2 - bx + 2 = 0, solve for the variable x"*?  What are *a* and *b*?

Comment: In y = ax^2 - bx + 2, a and b are (usually taken to be) unknown constants, while x and y are variables. The implication is that there is an infinite family of equations of the same form (eg y = 7x^2 - 4x + 2, y = x^2 - x + 2, y = 2.7x^2  + 2)

Comment: @GregLee, Edwin's got the right end up it.

Comment: Well, it's an oxymoron, but then so is "project manager", so it fits right in with the industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known oxymoron in computer programming. It arises because the term *variable* is not always used with its literal meaning. *variable* is often used to refer to any identifier created by the programmer that holds a value. Normally these can be reassigned, so they actually are variable. But many languages allow you to declare them with a *constant* modifier; they can be used in all the same contexts as ordinary variables, except as the target of an assignment.

Despite its derivation, the term *variable* encompasses these as well. There are too many situations where the distinction is irrelevant, so it would be inconvenient to have to say *variables and constants* all the time. Also, the term *constant* would be ambiguous, because it's usually used as a synonym for *literal* (e.g. numbers like `3` or strings like `"foo"`), so we'd need a different term for them.

In cases where it's important to distinguish them, we use the phrase *constant variable*.